# Keep a page alive via DevTools in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a way to keep a page alive in Chrome? I'm monitoring something on my router GUI and it's a pain to have to login again every few minutes.

I need a temporary solution which is why I wanted to go via devtools but it seems that the script I put in the console disappears on refresh.

```
localStorage.setItem('timer', 3 * 60 * 1000);
if (localStorage.getItem('timer') > 0) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.reload(1);
   }, localStorage.getItem('timer'));
}
```

This is what I have right now.

Comment: Use PHP to print that code and auto execute on refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the refresh will clear any user added code, unless you inject it again on refresh or as a MITM injection, you wont be able to achieve what you want.

What I would suggest would be to install an auto-refresh plugin, something like [Easy Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=en).

Comment: Yeah, the more I thought about this--it seems clearer that this is not possible through the console alone. I suppose a plugin would be best for this.